# Conditional String manipulation

Tags: r, string, conditional-statements

Hello I am trying to manipulate strings in a very specific way to get my data into stacked format. I am having trouble getting a '0' in the correct column based on column names.

Here is a sample of the df I am working with:

```
df<-data.frame(
Respondent = rep(8,4),
Set= seq(1:4),
Least_helpful = c("Customer service phone number", "Customer service phone number", "QR code to online chat","QR code to online chat"),
Most_helpful = c("Non-mobile device instructions", "Non-mobile device instructions", "Non-mobile device instructions", "Mobile device instructions"),
attr_shown = c("Non-mobile device instructions;Customer service phone number;Link to setup videos",
"Mobile device instructions;QR code to online chat;Link to setup videos",
"Non-mobile device instructions;QR code to online chat;Link to setup videos", "Mobile device instructions;Non-mobile device instructions;QR code to online chat"),
Customer_service_phone_number = c(-1,-1,NA,NA),
Non_mobile_device_instructions = c(1,1,1,NA),
Link_to_setup_videos = c(NA,NA,NA,NA),
Mobile_device_instructions = c(NA,NA,NA,1),
QR_code_to_online_chat = c(NA,NA,-1,-1)
                  )
```

Basically, there are 3 attributes shown in the 'attr_shown' column and what I am trying to do is to get a '0' in the corresponding column where the other 2 attributes were NOT selected as either most helpful or least helpful. For this particular respondent I would be trying to get a 0 in the 'Link_to_setup_videos' column for the first second and third row and a '0' in the "Non_mobile_device_instructions' for the fourth row. It should look like this when working properly:

[final_format_required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBGdm.png)

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to SO! Thanks for including an example of your input. In this case it might also be very helpful (and potentially avoid lengthy back and forth comments) to include an example of your expected output.

Comment: I added a photo of what it is supposed to look like when finished.